# How can I resolve 'Cross Origin Resource Sharing Error' when submitting enquiry form in AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, cors

I have a domain hosted in Godaddy. but need to do mail configuration through AWS lambda for static website. getting error "Cross Origin Resource Sharing Error" when submit enquiry form.

Done CORS configuration in lambda code and API GW also (attached screenshot)

This is lambda code

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new AWS.SES();
 
var RECEIVER1 = 'yyyyy@gmail.com';
var RECEIVER2 = 'xxxxx@gmail.com';
var SENDER = 'xxxxx@gmail.com';

var response = {
 "isBase64Encoded": false,
 "headers": { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': ''},
 "statusCode": 200,
 **headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
        },**
 "body": "{"result": "Success."}"
 };

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, { statusCode: 200, body: 'Hello from Lambda' });

};
 
function sendEmail (event, done) {
    var params = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: [
                RECEIVER1,RECEIVER2
            ]
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: {
                    Data: 'name: ' + event.name +'\nlastname: ' + event.lastname+ '\nphone: ' + event.phone+ '\nemail: ' + event.email+ '\nAddress: ' + event.address,
                    Charset: 'UTF-8'
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Data: 'Call Back Message from User ',
                Charset: 'UTF-8'
            }
        },
        Source: SENDER
    };
    ses.sendEmail(params, done);
}"
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TZXk.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyLJl.jpg)